# nText using Oracle gateway to MSSql

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I'm migrating data from sql server to oracle, I'v created the gateway but stuck with nText datatype! any idea how to transfer the data from nText to clob.

I know I can create view and convert ntext to nvarchar but my access to the sql server is readonly and the vendor refuse to give full access!!

Please help.

Comment: You don't mention what tool you're using to do the transfer. But in general, if the tool allows you to specify a query, then you can use the `SELECT` statement directly instead of creating a view.

Comment: As I mentioned above I've created a DB link in oracle and writing insert into .... select ... from sql server table. The problem is oracle can'r recognize any nText column in sql table. I've completed all tables without ntext column.